# CSS with ternary operator - only set property in one case

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'm using react native Platform API in my CSS as ternary operator.

For example, I'm setting the height:

```
height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 50,
```

However sometimes I want to set a property in one case but not in another case:

```
height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : <Don't set height>
```

What is the correct logic to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write another ternary operator as shown below

```
height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : Platform.OS === 'android' ? 50 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to set an explicit value, you can:

1) Only conditionally add the height property:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  styles.height = 40;
}
```

2) Use an undefined value:

```
height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : undefined,
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach i use is by making 2 style components :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  withHeight: {
    color: 'red',
height:40
  },
withoutHeight:{
color:'red'
}
});
```

So in your component you can do like :

```
<View style={Platform.OS =='ios'?styles.withHeight:styles.withoutheight}>
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you very much but the architecture is that the style is in one file so i must somehow select between ios or android inside the styling

Comment: what's the problem if the style is another file? even ive written codes where styles and code are different, here inside style you are just selecting the right style based on platform